# web application not running on windows xp without fiddler

Tags: c#, windows

we have a web application developed on .net4, and deployed on server 2008.
When exploring it from windows 7 it is running smoothly but with windows xp it gets hang
and when i use fiddler to diagnose the problem on windows xp, the application didnt hang and run over there too.
what could be the bottleneck which make it hangs without fiddler on windows xp. 
kindly suggest

Comment: Fiddler is just an HTTP traffic sniffer, it doesn't add or remove anything. The only explanation I could see is that fiddler was running then closed unexpectedly, and use of Fiddler as proxy wasn't removed from browser settings. In that case if you close fiddler properly, it should solve the problem.

Comment: yeah but when fiddler wasnt installed on that windows xp machine, application wasnt running that time also, so what could be the problem that is not diagnosed by fiddler, or should i say why my web application running from windows 7 not running from xp machine

Comment: Ok so that wasn't the origin of the problem. I however see no plausible explanation to this behaviour. Fiddler really act as a proxy for HTTP requests/responses from browsers and doesn't natively filter (=remove) anything. But when you say it hangs, does it evetually send a response, or is the request left unreplied ?